# Dynamically creating URLs for other websites

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic

I'd like to know how websites have created URLs with other domains like these on [trafficestimate.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:www.trafficestimate.com).

I'm guessing it's some .htaccess stuff to redirect domain names to a dynamic page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your URL has an [GET Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_methods). So when someone calls the page `http://google.com/search` with the parameters `hl=en`, `safe=off` etc., the page can process those parameters. So for instance `safe=off` means that you want to get back any search result. The `q=site:...` is your search string. In this case Google will look it up in its database and give you the results. So when you call this URL there is probably no .htaccess processing done. However you can process the URL and GET request with .htacces and i.e. redirect the user to another page.

Maybe you'll describe a bit further what exactly you trying to do/want to know. This makes explaining easier.

EDIT: After reading Gumbo's comment I looked at the Google result page. So maybe your question means the trafficestimate-URLs. They look like `http://trafficestimate.com/example.org`. This is really a good case for .htaccess. So using .htaccess they take the URL and redirect it to `http://www.trafficestimate.com/websites/?domain=example.org`. Here you have again a GET request and an application builds the page.

Comment: I think Rich meant the URLs that are shown in the search results.

Comment: You opened my eyes. :-) I understood the OP better and added some words.

Comment: Thanks a lot qbi, sorry for the poor phrasing! Yes, I was referring to the URLs that are shown in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Some [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) is probably involved. Otherwise they would have to create an existing file for every possible request.

Using [Apache’s mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in a .htaccess file is one option. But since the server identifies itself with “Microsoft-IIS/7.5”, they are probably rather using [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/), a mod_rewrite derivative for Microsoft’s IIS.

Comment: Microsoft ships a url-rewriting addon for IIS-7. The url-rewriting is configured in the application's `Web.config`.